# How do I link a plugin CSS and a normal CSS without one overriding the other?

Tags: jquery, html, css

How do I make my html be able to make the plugin CSS not override the normal CSS as I've tried many options. Here's my code:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="path/to/css/bootstrap-tabs-x-bs4.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="path/to/js/bootstrap-tabs-x.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<fieldset>
  <legend>Tabs Above Centered (Bordered)</legend>
</fieldset>

<div class="tabs-x align-center tabs-above tab-bordered">
  <!-- Nav tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
    <li role="presentation" class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" id="myTabDrop1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-controls="myTabDrop1-contents">
          Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="myTabDrop1" id="myTabDrop1-contents">
        <li><a href="#dropdown1" role="tab" id="dropdown1-tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="dropdown1">Dropdown 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#dropdown2" role="tab" id="dropdown2-tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="dropdown2">Dropdown 1</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active active" id="home">...</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="profile">...</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="settings">...</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="dropdown1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="dropdown1-tab">...</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="dropdown2" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="dropdown2-tab">...</div>
  </div>
</div>

<h1>Gaming</h1>

<h2>Have you ever felt a rush of adrenaline just by sitting? That's easily achievable with most video games. They take you to another world, one where you have nothing to worry about, and everything to love. </h2>

<h3>Now, many people are under the illusion that games are unhealthy and are the cause of many sicknesses. That is a wrong belief. Scientific reasearch has proved that playing games has nothing to do with your physical health and the only reason most people
  who play games are unhealthy is because of their lifestyle. In fact, they have been proved to help mental ability in some areas, and many people who play games are better at reacting quick and thinking fast. </h3>

<h4>THE WORLD IS GETTING INCREASINGLY INVOLVED IN GAMING. YOU SHOULD TOO</h4>
```

But I've also tried importing in my CSS but the plugin doesn't work properly. same with copy-pasting the plugin code in my CSS

Comment: The simple answer is you can't. The only thing you can do is change the order of the files. So the last css file will overwrite the files that come before it

Comment: Or use different classes so they do not clash

Comment: like @Pete said, you can for example prefix your plugin's classes with your pluginsname (eg: myplugin-tab) so it doesnt interfere with your main css

Comment: By “CSS plugin” you are referring to the whole Bootstrap framework here, or what exactly?